# Calling object destructor whose type is nested inside of a class?

Tags: c++11, destructor, using, placement-new, typename

Suppose a `class` contains a type defined by a nested `using` whose destructor needs to be explicitly invoked. Is it necessary to use `using` to create a local type that doesn't include the namespace separator (`::`)?

In this contrived example, I want to call `A::WeakPtr`'s destructor, like:

```cpp
wp->~A::WeakPtr();
```

instead of like:

```cpp
using AWeakPtr = A::WeakPtr;
wp->~AWeakPtr()
```

Is this doable? Here's a complete example.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
  using SharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<A>;
  using WeakPtr = std::weak_ptr<A>;

  A()  { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
  ~A() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

int
main() {
  {
    std::unique_ptr<A::WeakPtr, void(*)(void*)>
        uwp(static_cast<A::WeakPtr*>(std::malloc(sizeof(A::WeakPtr))), std::free);
    A::WeakPtr* wp = uwp.get();

    {
      auto sp = std::make_shared<A>();
      new(wp) A::WeakPtr(sp);

      if (wp->lock())
        std::cout << "Locked\n";
      else
        std::cout << "Unlocked\n";
    }

    if (wp->lock())
      std::cerr << "EUNPOSSIBLE\n";
    else
      std::cout << "Unable to obtain lock\n";

    // Need the following 'using' statement because the following is invalid syntax:
    // wp->~A::WeakPtr();
    using AWeakPtr = A::WeakPtr;
    wp->~AWeakPtr();
    // Is there a way to call A::WeakPtr without the using statement?
  }
  std::cout << "memory held by uwp has been free(3)'ed\n";
}
```

It seems like there should be a way to defeat the `::` namespace separator with a `typename` scattered in there somewhere, but it doesn't look like it's possible. Obviously it's not the end of the world if it's not possible, but my curio is getting the better of me.

---

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @DanielFrey and @DyP's [fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061195/736571), the correct syntax is indeed

```cpp
wp->A::WeakPtr::~WeakPtr();
```

but this doesn't work and is a bug ([#12350](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12350)) in clang++ (as of 2013-09-28).

Comment: A helper function is also possible: `template<class T> void destroy(T& t) {  t.~T();  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destructor call using a *qualified-id* here must consist of:

*postfix-expression* `->` *nested-name-specifier* `~` *class-name* `()`

The *postfix-expression* here is `wp`, and the part after `->` forms a **single** *qualified-id* (w/o the parens).

Grammatically, the following is also possible:

*postfix-expression* `->` *nested-name-specifier* `~` *decltype-specifier* `()`

However, this second form is forbidden explicitly in [expr.prim.general]/9:

> The form `~ decltype-specifier` also denotes the destructor, but it shall not be used as the *unqualified-id* in a *qualified-id*.

The *class-name* in the first form can also be a *typedef-name* [class.name]/5:

> A *typedef-name* (7.1.3) that names a class type, or a *cv*-qualified version thereof, is also a *class-name*.

For the lookup of this *class-name* after the `~`, there's a special name lookup rule in [basic.lookup.qual]/5:

> Similarly, in a *qualified-id* of the form:
>        *nested-name-specifier*<sub>opt</sub> *class-name* `:: ~` *class-name*
>   the second *class-name* is looked up in the same scope as the first.

This means that the second `WeakPtr` in `A::WeakPtr :: ~WeakPtr` should be found. It is a *typedef-name* naming a class, therefore a *class-name*, and it's looked up in the scope of `A`. gcc follows this rule, clang++3.4 does not.

Therefore, `wp->A::WeakPtr :: ~WeakPtr();` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061156/420683) by [Daniel Frey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073257/daniel-frey) (and my first, deleted comment/guess) should work.

---

Alternative approaches:

1. Using a helper function:

   ```
   template<class T>
   void destroy(T& t)
   { t.~T(); }
   ```
2. Using a *decltype-specifier* w/o a *qualified-id*. This one is tricky, as the type of `decltype(*wp)` is `A::WeakPtr&`, as `*wp` yields an lvalue. However, we can convert the the expression to a prvalue to get rid of the reference:

   ```
   wp->~decltype((A::WeakPtr)*wp)();
   // alternatively, w/o explicitly mentioning the type:
   wp->~decltype((std::remove_pointer<decltype(wp)>::type)*wp)();
   // simpler, using a helper function again:
   template<class T>  T helper(T const&);
   wp->~decltype(helper(*wp))();
   ```

---

Production:

Begin with the function call [expr.post]/1:

> *postfix-expression* `(` *expression-list*<sub>opt</sub> `)`

Where the *postfix-expression* here is produced via:

> *postfix-expression* `-> template`<sub>opt</sub> *id-expression*

This *postfix-expression* here maps to `wp` (in `wp->~something()`).

The id-expression contains the destructor "name" [expr.prim.general]:

> *id-expression:*
>        *unqualified-id*
>        *qualified-id*

We do need a *qualified-id* here, so [expr.prim.general]/8:

> *qualified-id:*
>        *nested-name-specifier* `template`<sub>opt</sub> *unqualified-id*
>        `::` *identifier*
>        `::` *operator-function-id*
>        `::` *literal-operator-id*
>        `::` template-id

Only the first one is of interest, so we look at *unqualified-id* s:

> *unqualified-id:*
>        *identifier*
>        *operator-function-id*
>        *conversion-function-id*
>        *literal-operator-id*
>        `~` *class-name*
>        `~` *decltype-specifier*
>        *template-id*

Where the two with a `~` can be used to call a destructor.

Comment: Ah! @DyP, it is indeed that same bug. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for

```
wp->A::WeakPtr::~WeakPtr();
```

?

Comment: Oops, sorry, there's a special name lookup rule. Now I don't know what to think about it :/

Comment: @DyP First of all +1 for your answer for trying to verify what is and is not standard conforming. I'm currently way too tired to check the standard, I'm going to suspend mode now ;) Also, if OP needs a work-around the helper function you suggested looks good to me as it simply avoids the problem Clang seems to have.

Comment: @DanielFrey I tried that, but it didn't work. `error: expected the class name after '~' to name a destructor`. As @DyP pointed out, this is a bug in the frontend of clang. `Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.75) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix`

Comment: @Sean What compiler (+version) are you using? I tested it with GCC 4.8 and it works and I *think* it is standard conforming. DyP also came to the same conclusion, but he also found out Clang has a problem which requires a work-around (and he provided several work-arounds). (Just say your edited comment, so yeah, Clang needs a work-around :)

Comment: I'm used to compiler bugs being a gcc feature and it didn't even cross my mind that clang would have a compiler bug they've been so rare for me. :) Anyway, much appreciated.